# Why jQuery :not selector attribute doesn't work for this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code which works as expected:

**First Approach**

```js
$('ul').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<li>foo</li>');
})
.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

What it does is simple:

- It adds one li element when any bullet point is clicked
- Ignores any click inside li elements

I'm cool with that is the behavior I want. With this approach It seems like bullet points are not part of the li elements because any click performed on the bullet points are not going trough the second function.

**My problem raised** after I thought that I could refactor the javascript code a little bit, passing it a ":not(li)" selector as parameter in the first call.

**Second Approach**:

```
$('ul').on('click', ":not(li)", function(e) {
    $(this).append('<li>foo</li>');
});
```

But it turned out that is behaving different, I don't understand why is not adding li elements after bullet points are clicked.

Second approach looks cleaner but opposite of what we saw in the first approach, is like the bullets point were part of the li elements.

-Why the second approach is behaving different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `ul :not(li)` will select any descendants of a `ul` that is not a `li` element.

Since your `ul` element only contains `li` elements, the event never gets fired. However, if the `li` elements contained a `span` element, the event would get fired when clicking on the `span` element, but that isn't the desired result.

Rather than suppressing the event when clicking on an `li` element, I'd simply suggest checking if `this` is equal to `e.target`. This is similar to your first example.

```js
$('ul').on('click', function(e) {
  if (this === e.target) {
    $(this).append('<li>foo</li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With that being said, is like jquery uses the selector for filter elements before get fired the click event, and because there is not any elements in ul the click event does not get fired. Which is different that when there is no any selector for filter, the click event will get fired